# what regex or functionality require to get the data from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,   //https://www.linkedin.com/company/666511/
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
console.log(data)

//response comes in 2000 lines  
here is the sample short response

[&quot;Web Development&quot;,&quot;Professional Training&quot;,&quot;Apprenticeship&quot;,&quot;Nonprofit&quot;]
,
&quot;companyPageUrl&quot;:&quot;http://www.thedifferenceengine.io&quot;

//i only want this link to return
http://www.thedifferenceengine.io
}
});
```

> i dont understant what regex or jquery require or how i remove this &quote and get companypageurl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
/http:[^;]+/
```

```js
let str = '[&quot;Web Development&quot;,&quot;Professional Training&quot;,&quot;Apprenticeship&quot;,&quot;Nonprofit&quot;],&quot;companyPageUrl&quot;:&quot;http://www.thedifferenceengine.io&quot;'

console.log(str.match(/http:[^;]+/));
```

Comment: if i have mulitple links comes in response than how i search the speicfic url like companyurl

Comment: does it have a pattern, then you can modify the regex to incorporate the company name as well

Comment: one more think  when i get the response than reponse not only show the json lots of other thing its like a whole page html than in between json come  how i put all the html into var str =  '[data]'   it cannot search

Comment: can you please tell me regular expression that ends with .com or .io your regular expression result like this http://www.thedifferenceengine.io&quot i want this  url   http://www.thedifferenceengine.io or .com

Comment: use the regex /http[^;]+\.(?:com|io)/

Answer (score 0):

```
 var decode ='[&quot;Web Development&quot;,&quot;Professional Training&quot;,&quot;Apprenticeship&quot;,&quot;Nonprofit&quot;],&quot;companyPageUrl&quot;:&quot;http://www.thedifferenceengine.io&quot;';

 alert($("<div/>").html(decode).text());
```